# jQuery not working after addition of noUiSlider jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, nouislider

I want to delete a table row by clicking on its child element.

```
  //cart remove line
  $('.cartlineremove').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
  });
```

This has been tested and it works.

However when I add in some other jQuery methods (some functionality for another php page, but all my jQuery is in main.js), the delete icons no longer work. Why?

```
        //on search page, price range slider
        var handlesSlider = document.getElementById('slider-handles');
          noUiSlider.create(handlesSlider, {
            start: [ 0, 5000 ],

            range: {
                'min': [ 0 ],
                'max': [ 5000 ]
            },
            format: wNumb({
                decimals: 0
            })
          });

          var inputPriceMin = document.getElementById('pricemin');
          var inputPriceMax = document.getElementById('pricemax');

          handlesSlider.noUiSlider.on('update', function( values, handle ) {

            var value = values[handle];

            if ( handle ) {
                inputPriceMax.value = value;
            } else {
                inputPriceMin.value = value;
            }
          });

          inputPriceMin.addEventListener('change', function(){
            handlesSlider.noUiSlider.set([this.value, null]);
          });

          inputPriceMax.addEventListener('change', function(){
            handlesSlider.noUiSlider.set([null, this.value]);
          });


          handlesSlider.noUiSlider.on('change', function(){
            var $form = $('#filterform');
            var formData = $form.serialize();
            $('#pricespinner').addClass('active');
            $.post('find.php', formData, function(response){
              // do something with response
              $('#results').load('results.php');
              // do something with response ends
            })
            .done(function() {
              $('#pricespinner').removeClass('active');
            })

            .fail(function(){
              alert("Oops something bad happened");
            });
          });

  //on cart page, cart remove line 
  $('.cartlineremove').click(function(e) {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove()
  });
```

I have a feeling that it is due to the noUiSlider DOM, but what exactly made it so such that the moment I add in the price range slider jQuery, the delete icon stopped working?

Updated https://jsfiddle.net/sq66f4ak/5/.

Try removing the noUIslider jQuery and you will see that the remove icon works, why?

Comment: Check the errors thrown in browser dev tools console. Demo immediately tells you that  uiSlider is not a function...which means a dependency is missing

Comment: @charlietfI the dependency wasnt added in the fiddle but it is in my project. The price range slider works but when added together with the delete table row function, the latter fails to work. Ill try add the dependency in the fiddle

Comment: but the broader point is...do you have any errors showing?

Comment: @charlietfl You're right there is an error in the console, even though everything works in the price range slider page. In the remove table row there is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null', in the price range slider page there is 'Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined'

Comment: well the `$ not defined` is easy to search

Comment: @charlietfI Yea I got that one, it is in a totally unrelated page and it's fine now. I think the problem is the nodeName inside noUiSlider's js. Not sure how to over come that one though.

Answer (score 0):

In your js fiddle, the `noUiSlider.create` failed with error.Did this also happen with your real code? Any previous script error will leads to the last event bind not working. Try to move the remove icon click to the top of your script to test.

Comment: the noUiSlider worked fine in my project. I'll update the JSfiddle to include the dependency.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that putting the remove icon click script to the top will work, that has the same effect as removing the noUiSlider jQuery, the thing is why?

Comment: If you updated the fiddle with correct noUiSlider source, it is still failed with error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null`. I suggest that keep your console open when you debug your web.As I said in my answer.The `noUiSlider` still have problems in your app.